# Image pre-processing parameters for tensorflow models

Tags: android, ios, tensorflow

I have a basic question about how to determine the image pre-processing parameters like - "IMAGE_MEAN", "IMAGE_STD" for various tensorflow pre-trained models. The Android sample applications for TensorFlow provides these parameters for a certain inception_v3 model in the ClassifierActivity.java (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/android/src/org/tensorflow/demo/ClassifierActivity.java) as shown below -

"If you want to use a model that's been produced from the TensorFlow for Poets codelab, you'll need to set IMAGE_SIZE = 299, IMAGE_MEAN = 128, IMAGE_STD = 128"

How do I determine these parameters for other TF models

Also, while converting the TF model to CoreML model, to be used on iOS, there are additional image pre-processing parameters that need to be specified (like - red_bias, green_bias, blue_bias and image_scale) as shown in the code segment below. The below parameters are for inception_v1_2016.pb model. If I want to use another pre-trained model like - ResNet50, MobileNet, etc how do I determine these parameters

```
tf_converter.convert(tf_model_path = 'inception_v1_2016_08_28_frozen.pb',
                 mlmodel_path = 'InceptionV1.mlmodel',
                 output_feature_names = ['InceptionV1/Logits/Predictions/Softmax:0'],
                 image_input_names = 'input:0',
                 class_labels = 'imagenet_slim_labels.txt',
                 red_bias = -1,
                 green_bias = -1,
                 blue_bias = -1,
                 image_scale = 2.0/255.0
                 )
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Guys any response to the above question? I have read through a lot of articles but all of them specify mean subtraction for preprocessing. What I do t understand in the Android Tensorflow example is - how is the mean constant across all input images for a certain TF model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the preprocessing requirements of various ImageNet models are still under documented. ResNet and VGG models both use the same preprocessing parameters. You can find biases for each of the color channels here:

https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-models/blob/master/imagenet_utils.py#L11

The preprocessing for Inception_V3, MobileNet, and other models can be found in the individual model files of this repo: https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-models

When converting to Core ML you always need to specify preprocessing biases on a per channel basis. So in the case of a VGG-type preprocessing, you can just copy each channel's biases directly from the code linked to above. It's super important to note that the biases are applied (added) BEFORE scaling. You can read more about setting the proper values here: http://machinethink.net/blog/help-core-ml-gives-wrong-output/

The conversion code you posted looks good for MobileNet or Inception_V3 models, but would not work for VGG or ResNet. For those you'd need:

```
tf_converter.convert(...
    red_bias=-123.68,
    green_bias=-116.78,
    blue_bias=-103.94
)
```

No scaling is required.